# build recent numpy on recent ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy

How do I build numpy 1.5 on ubuntu 10.10?
The instructions I found seems outdated or not clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `pip` to install after getting the required compiler/build tools:

```
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential
wget http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py && sudo python ./distribute_setup.py
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install numpy
```

I used `easy_install` to get `pip` and then `pip` to get `numpy`.

Comment: What about numpy dependencies? pip can only take care of python dependencies but not OS dependencies. Someone suggested to install the foloowing packages: python-dev libatlas-base-dev python-nose. The numpy docs say to install nose instead of python-nose because python-nose is buggy. What about the build_ext --fcompiler=gnu95 install option? http://advice.mechanicalkern.com/question/15/how-to-build-numpyscipy-on-ubuntu-or-debian

Comment: I don't know about any of those things. I do know that when I executed the instructions above, I got a working version of 1.5.0: `import numpy; numpy.version.version; '1.5.0'`

Answer (score 2):

One way to try, which isn't guaranteed to work, but worth a shot is to see if uupdate can sucessfully update the package.  Get a tarball of numpy 1.5.  run "apt-get source numpy" which should fetch and unpack the current source from ubuntu.  cd into this source directory and run "uupdate ../numpytarballname".  This should update the old source package using the newer tarball.  then you can try building with "apt-get build-dep numpy" and "dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot".  This will require you have the build-essential and fakeroot packages installed.